# Is descent from mountain to jungle normally barred by thorn bushes?

Tags: mountains, forests, tropic, jungle, andes

Reading *River of Darkness: Francisco Orellana's Legendary Voyage of Death and Discovery Down the Amazon*, starting on page 27, the section where the Spaniards are descending from the Andes towards the Amazon basin:

> ... spent each day literally hacking roads and trails with machetes... came to very rugged wooded country, and great mountain ranges through which we were obliged to open up new roads, not only for the men but for the horses... seventy interminable days hacking through clogged and brambly forest... cut a swath through the forest with adzes, axes, machetes... faces sliced by vines and thorns and spines of the understory.

That is a very clear and vivid description of the terrain, that I'm trying to make sense of because it does not at all correspond to anything I've seen in documentary videos about tropical environments. The videos I've seen, show relatively open forest floor, which makes sense because the canopy soaks up most of the sunlight, leaving little to sustain understory plants.

Now maybe the problem is the intermediate zone. High enough altitude, there is little or no vegetation. Maybe as you descend, you reach a zone with conditions suitable for plenty of vegetation but not outright trees, leaving everything at just the right height to block travel?

I haven't seen anything like that in documentaries, but maybe I haven't been looking at the right ones? Is there something about the Andes that makes it different from other tropical mountains like Kilimanjaro, the Himalayas or New Guinea?

Of course, anyone traveling that way *now* would use existing roads and trails, but my interest in this is that I am writing a story set in pre-Columbian South America. My fictional exploring party is very different in nature from the Spanish one, consisting of just two men with no animals, lightly equipped and living off the land as they go. I hoped they would have an easier time; an exploring party of two men is much more agile than a small army with horses as Pizarro brought. But the above description suggests it doesn't matter; the described terrain should block two men on foot just as thoroughly as a cavalry army.

In fact, my exploring party would face worse prospects, not better, because if you have to carve a path through the jungle, a larger party would be better able to do this! And given the difficulty Pizarro's army had, that suggests my party would find the intermediate vegetation zone to be an impassable barrier.

That's inconvenient for the story (given that I'm trying to be geographically accurate), and highly counterintuitive. I'd like to understand whether I'm missing something here. Is there really no way for a small agile party to slip through the vegetation?

Comment: Remember the Andes are nearly 4400 miles long, so expect many differences. You should assume that it was very thorny **in the location Pizarro was descending** but you shouldn't assume that is the same for the entire length of the mountain range.

Comment: When descending from above the tree line into a forest, it isn't like you immediately enter into giant tall trees. There is usually a band of lower-growing stuff that can be a real pain to get through, be it heath, or rhododendrons, or blackberry bushes, or ...

Comment: I can only speak for a small part of the Ituri Rainforest (that I visited), but the undergrowth is not sparse, and vines trying to reach some area with more light seemed very plentiful. We didn't need to hack away to get through, but a lot of dodging was involved. The Hoh Rainforest (temperate) is equally lush and difficult to navigate unless on a trail. Not all rainforests are the same.

Comment: AFAIK the whole jungle is about thorns and bushes, and you use more hands than legs to move...